# Unlikely argument type String for contains(Object) on a Collection<String[]>

Tags: java, string, arraylist, types, contains

I'm getting the warning in Eclipse:

> Unlikely argument type `String` for `contains(Object)` on a `Collection<String[]>`

Is there a way to modify the code so as to not get this warning?

```
String[] findNames = {"shares","ticker","avgCost","mktPrice","gnLs","totVal"};    

ArrayList<String[]> publicNames = new ArrayList<String[]>();        
for(Field publicField : publicFields) {
    String[] name = new String[2];
    name[0] = publicField.getName();
    name[1] = publicField.getType().toString();
    publicNames.add(name);           
} 

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {           
    if(publicNames.contains(findNames[i])) {
        System.out.println("\n***** Warning: instance variable " 
                           + findNames[i] 
                           + " declared as \"public\" *****\n ");               
    }           
}
```

Comment: How could a List<String[]> contain a String? A String is not a String[]. That's what the warning is telling you. You're looking for an apple in a box of oranges.

Comment: There are two ways: either make `publicNames` an `ArrayList<String>` or call `contains` with a `String[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because publicNames is an `ArrayList` of `string[]` and you're trying to see if it contains a single string, which is not applicable.

Now I don't know why you are storing tuples of strings and then types. I'd advise you to change this way, but if you really need them, you might want to look at @Deadpool's answer

```
ArrayList<String> publicNames = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now this line won't throw any warning

```
publicNames.contains(findNames[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare `String` with `String array`, If you want to find `String` value contains in list of String array, `List<String[]>`

You can do this by using java-8 streams

```
publicNames.stream().flatMap(Arrays::stream).anyMatch(item->item.equals(findNames[i]))
```

> will return true if any of `String[]` in `publicNames` contains `findNames[i]`, or will return false